# How to change the effect in swiper

Tags: javascript, html, swipe, swiper.js

In a swiper, I want it perform different effect, For example. performs 'fade' from slide1 to slide2, and performs 'cube' from slide2 to slide3 and performs 'slide' from slide3 to slide4.

How to do it ?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can (or would want to) set the effects differently for every slide -- it would not be recognisable as a swiper to the user if you did that,

However to use any of the effects you for example set the "effect" to "cube"

```
  var myswiper = new Swiper('.myswiper', {
     direction: 'horizontal'
     loop: true,
     effect: "cube", // select effect cube
     cube: {         // set the options
         slideShadows: true,
         shadow: true,
         shadowOffset: 20,
         shadowScale: 0.94
    }});
```

See the [documentation](http://www.idangero.us/swiper/api/) for more explanation

Comment: Hi, any change on this?

Answer (score 0):

You can't, according to the documentation only settings which are not required different layout and logic can be changed.

See the [documentation](https://swiperjs.com/api/) for more explanation.

Comment: Hi, any change on this?